# Could not get the JAWT interface error on mac

Tags: java, macos, runtime-error, lwjgl, jawt

I'm trying to run the Basic Demo of the JBullet library. However it's giving saying JAWT interface couldn't be found. It works fine on Windows 8 Pro and Ubuntu 13.10 (I've tested them on my laptop) but not on my mac running OS X 10.8.5 with Oracle Java 7.

[image]

Here's the complete exception.

```
org.lwjgl.LWJGLException: Could not get the JAWT interface
    at org.lwjgl.opengl.AWTSurfaceLock.lockAndInitHandle(Native Method)
    at org.lwjgl.opengl.AWTSurfaceLock.access$100(AWTSurfaceLock.java:49)
    at org.lwjgl.opengl.AWTSurfaceLock$1.run(AWTSurfaceLock.java:89)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.lwjgl.opengl.AWTSurfaceLock.privilegedLockAndInitHandle(AWTSurfaceLock.java:86)
    at org.lwjgl.opengl.AWTSurfaceLock.lockAndGetHandle(AWTSurfaceLock.java:64)
    at org.lwjgl.opengl.MacOSXCanvasPeerInfo.initHandle(MacOSXCanvasPeerInfo.java:53)
    at org.lwjgl.opengl.MacOSXDisplayPeerInfo.doLockAndInitHandle(MacOSXDisplayPeerInfo.java:56)
    at org.lwjgl.opengl.PeerInfo.lockAndGetHandle(PeerInfo.java:85)
    at org.lwjgl.opengl.MacOSXContextImplementation.create(MacOSXContextImplementation.java:46)
    at org.lwjgl.opengl.Context.<init>(Context.java:113)
    at org.lwjgl.opengl.Display.create(Display.java:783)
    at org.lwjgl.opengl.Display.create(Display.java:733)
    at com.bulletphysics.demos.opengl.LWJGL.main(LWJGL.java:54)
    at com.bulletphysics.demos.basic.BasicDemo.main(BasicDemo.java:228)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at com.sun.javaws.Launcher.executeApplication(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javaws.Launcher.executeMainClass(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javaws.Launcher.doLaunchApp(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javaws.Launcher.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)
```

Can anybody say what is the cause of it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of problems.

- The version of lwjgl that ships with the jbullet code **does not** work with Java 7 on Mac OS X
- the JBullet code needs to be changed to work on the newer lwjgl

Solutions/Workarounds:

- Use a 1.6 run-time
- fix the jbullet code to work on a newer version of lwjgl.

Note: You cannot use the webstart launcher for the demo if you've got Java 7 installed; it will simply not work.

What I did to get it to work:

- Downloaded the jbullet code
- ran with the 1.6 VM using:

  ```
  /usr/libexec/java_home -v 1.6 --exec java -Djava.library.path=(pwd)/lib/lwjgl/macosx -cp dist/\*:(pwd)/lib/lwjgl/\* com.bulletphysics.demos.basic.BasicDemo
  ```

In this case, I installed the full 1.6 JDK from the apple downloads site; I think you can do `/usr/libexec/java_home -R -v 1.6` to get it to explicitly install the 1.6 JRE, which should work with this demo.

Comment: I replaced the LWJGL jars that came with JBullet with the latest ones and it ran perfectly with Java 7.

Comment: I had to follow the [fixes at this link](http://blog.lolyco.com/sean/2011/05/14/trying-out-jbullet-intbuffer-is-not-direct/) to get the demo working under the newer lwjgl, so I'm surprised it worked OOB for you